# vim configuration: search highlight

Tags: vim

set hlsearch .   when I search something , the choiced words change to white ,but all the word is white default . but how can the word choiced can have a different background to show it . Thanks for you help .
this is my vimrc

```
    set autoread
    set autoindent
    set ai "auto indent
    set bsdir=buffer
    set background=dark
    set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-
    set completeopt=longest,menu
    set t_Co=256
    set expandtab
    set foldmethod=indent
    set foldlevelstart=99
    set number
    set nobackup
    set nocompatible
    set ruler
    set tabstop=4
    set t_Co=256
    set hlsearch
    set laststatus=2
    set showmatch
    set showcmd
    set syn=cpp
    set shiftwidth=4
    set smarttab
    set smartindent
    set selection=exclusive
    set selectmode=mouse,key
    set si

    if v:lang =~ "utf8$" || v:lang =~ "UTF-8$"
       set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
    endif

    set nocompatible    " Use Vim defaults (much better!)
    set bs=indent,eol,start     " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
    "set ai         " always set autoindenting on
    "set backup     " keep a backup file
    set viminfo='20,\"50    " read/write a .viminfo file, don't store more
                " than 50 lines of registers
    set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
    set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time

    " Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands
    if has("autocmd")
      augroup redhat
      autocmd!
      " In text files, always limit the width of text to 78 characters
      autocmd BufRead *.txt set tw=78
      " When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
      autocmd BufReadPost *
      \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
      \   exe "normal! g'\"" |
      \ endif
      " don't write swapfile on most commonly used directories for NFS mounts or USB sticks
      autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPre /media/*,/mnt/* set directory=~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
      " start with spec file template
      autocmd BufNewFile *.spec 0r /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/template.spec
      augroup END
    endif

    if has("cscope") && filereadable("/usr/bin/cscope")
       set csprg=/usr/bin/cscope
       set csto=0
       set cst
       set nocsverb
       " add any database in current directory
       if filereadable("cscope.out")
          cs add cscope.out
       " else add database pointed to by environment
       elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
          cs add $CSCOPE_DB
       endif
       set csverb
    endif

    " Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
    " Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
    if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
      syntax on
      set hlsearch
    endif

    filetype plugin on


    if &term=="xterm"
         set t_Co=8
         set t_Sb=[4%dm
         set t_Sf=[3%dm
    endif

    " Don't wake up system with blinking cursor:
    " http://www.linuxpowertop.org/known.php
    let &guicursor = &guicursor . ",a:blinkon0"

    set background=dark
    "set background=light

    colorscheme desert

    set incsearch " 即刻显示当前输入的搜索结果
```

Answer (score 2):

Either switch the colorscheme, or modify it. The following needs to be put **after the :colorscheme command** in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
highlight Search ctermbg=yellow ctermfg=black guibg=yellow guifg=black
```

If you switch colorschemes on the fly, you also need this:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight Search ctermbg=yellow ctermfg=black guibg=yellow guifg=black
```

If the search-as-you-type highlighting is also affected, add a similar override for the `IncSearch` highlight group.

Comment: "after the :colorscheme command", thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can change the highlight color in each mode using `:highlight` command

To change the highlight text's color use

```
  :highlight Search guifg=Red
```

To change the highlight text's background use

```
  :highlight Search guibg=Green
```

Refer `:help highlight-guifg` to know more about the options supported

Comment: Works for me. Close your VIM session and open again or 
run `:source $MYVIMRC`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
:highlight Search guibg=yellow guifg=black
```

to show the matching text in yellow background and black foreground.